# Angular : How to disable buttons creating via ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm creating an html table. In which there is cell of a button and a dropdown creating via **ngFor**.  How to disable buttons(generated via **ngFor**) if no value selected from dropdown. I've tried this :

In **AppComponent** I've something like this:

**ts**

```
customers: Array<Object> = [];
level: string;

changedvalue(event: Event) {
   const value = (<HTMLSelectElement>event.target).value;
   this.level = value;
  }
```

**html**

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">
     <td> {{ customer.uid }} </td>

     <td> {{ customer.name }} </td>

     <td> {{ customer.level }}</td>

     <td>
     <select (change)="changedvalue($event)" class="form-control" name="level">
        <option  hidden selected> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option>Level 1</option>
        <option>Level 2</option>
     </select>
     </td>

    <td><button [disabled]=!level >Send</button></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
```

the problem with this code is that it's enbaling all the buttons if select value from any of the dropdown. What I want is to enable only that button whoes infront of that dropdown. How to relate each button to each dropdown which I'm creating via **ngFor**.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should store some value within `customer` so each iteration will have its own `level` variable. I changed the method name according to conventions.

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">
         <td> {{ customer.uid }} </td>

         <td> {{ customer.name }} </td>

         <td> {{ customer.level }}</td>

         <td>
         <select (change)="onLevelChange($event, customer)" class="form-control" name="level">
            <option  hidden selected> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option>Level 1</option>
            <option>Level 2</option>
         </select>
         </td>

        <td><button [disabled]=!customer.level >Send</button></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```js
customers: Array<Object> = [];

onLevelChange(event: Event, customer) {
   const value = (<HTMLSelectElement>event.target).value;
   customer.level = value;
   // if compiler complains as "there is no level property of customer"
   // you can do following
   // customer['level'] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Add level to your customer model manually and then do the following

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">
     <td> {{ customer.uid }} </td>

     <td> {{ customer.name }} </td>

     <td> {{ customer.level }}</td>

     <td>
     <select (change)="customer.level = !customer.level" class="form-control" name="level">
        <option  hidden selected> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option>Level 1</option>
        <option>Level 2</option>
     </select>
     </td>

    <td><button [disabled]=!customer.level >Send</button></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom property to your `customers` object.

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2m8ns7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Example code:

```
<div *ngFor="let c of customers; let i = index">
  <span>{{c.name}} {{c.surname}} | is Enabled? : {{c.isEnabled}}</span> 
  <button (click)="toggleMe(i)">Toggle status</button>
</div>
```

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public customers : any[] = [];

  constructor(){
     this.customers = [
    {
      name: "Jhon",
      surname: "Cena",
      isEnabled: false
    },

    {
      name: "Mike",
      surname: "Mya",
      isEnabled: false
    },

    {
      name: "Sandy",
      surname: "Rivers",
      isEnabled: false
    }
  ];
  }

  toggleMe(i){
    this.customers[i].isEnabled = !this.customers[i].isEnabled;
  }
}
```